# Why does not work the xml layout page

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Why does not work xml layout? I get an error message when I open layout page, please help me, what's the problem,  I don't understand, any ideas ? thanks for answer...

My xml layout code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="440dp" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bck2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonprevious"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/lefticon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonnext"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/righticon" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat error message;

```
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.hayvansesleri/com.hayvansesleri.Pictures}:     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to     android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.hayvansesleri.Pictures.onCreate(Pictures.java:38)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
10-29 16:26:13.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     ... 11 more
```

pictures.class;

```
public class Pictures extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnClickListener  {
protected static final Context Context = null;

private static final int count = 23;
private AdController myController;
SoundManager snd; 

View view=null;

final Activity act = this;  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInsta,mknceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picturespage);


 MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
 final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
 myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 myPager.setCurrentItem(12); 
 myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
 snd = new SoundManager(this);
 this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

 Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
 next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View v) {
         myPager.setCurrentItem(myPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
     }
 }); 

 Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonprevious);
 previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View v) {
         myPager.setCurrentItem(myPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
     }
 }); 
 };
```

Comment: please post the error message from logcat

Comment: check your super.onCreate() call 'savedInsta' should be savedInstanceState

Answer (score 5, accepted):

juned may be right, try running «ant clean» on your project. Sometimes R.java becomes outdated without build system noticing. You could e.g. exchange the order of Button and ViewPager in your xml file, but the generated id`s in R.id class stays in wrong order. «ant clean» before «ant release»/«ant debug» fixes that.